# Writing small numbers in Latex figures

Tags: latex

I have a basic figure where I want the following numbers to be in the Y axis
0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1

When I write them in the code they appear in a different way as you see in the screenshot.
I know this is mathematically correct but they look odd and I want to them to be shown exactly as I put them in the code.

[image]

this is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [style={outer sep=5}]
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=0.1, xmin=15, xmax=50,
xtick={15,20,...,50},
ytick={0,0.01,...,0.1},
grid={major},clip=false,grid style={dashed},
title={},
legend style={at={(1.2 ,1)},anchor=north},
font=\footnotesize]

% 25
\addplot[color=green, mark=*, samples=10] [error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {
(15, 0.0032)
(20, 0.0039) 
(25, 0.0052) 
(30, 0.007)
(35, 0.009)
(40, 0.0095) 
(45, 0.01)
(50, 0.012)
};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The other figure code is

```
    \begin{figure} [H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [style={outer sep=5}]
\begin{axis}[ymin=0.004,ymax=0.018, xmin=15, xmax=50,
xlabel= $Number of Nodes$, ylabel = $end-to-end (sec)$,
xtick={15,20,...,50},
ytick={0.004,0.005,...,0.018},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
grid={major},clip=false,grid style={dashed},
title={},
legend style={at={(1.2 ,1)},anchor=north},
font=\footnotesize]

% TAODV
\addplot[color=blue, mark=*, samples=10] [error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {
(15, 0.0072) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(20, 0.0079) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(25, 0.0092) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(30, 0.01) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(35, 0.013) +-(0.0018, -0.0018)
(40, 0.0137) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(45, 0.015) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(50, 0.0168)+-(0.001, -0.001)
};

% AODV
\addplot[color=red, mark=*, samples=10] [error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {
(15, 0.0052) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(20, 0.0057) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(25, 0.0067) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(30, 0.0074) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(35, 0.0082) +-(0.0018, -0.0018)
(40, 0.0095) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(45, 0.01) +-(0.001, -0.001)
(50, 0.0109) +-(0.001, -0.001)
};

\legend{
    $TAODV$,
    $AODV$
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[End-to-end delay of TAODV vs. AODV]{End-to-end delay of TAODV vs. AODV with \%95 confidence interval}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] including all the necessary packages etc.

Comment: Unrelated: using math mode for `$TAODV$` etc isn't a good idea. This will mess up all the kerning between letters. Just look at the wide space between the T and the A and how the D nearly touches the V...

Comment: The package I am using to create the figure is pgfplots

Comment: You should edit your question to provide a single, compilable code block which we can copy and paste to recreate your problem.

Comment: I've updated the code. Now you can copy and paste it and it will work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed}` to change the number format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} [style={outer sep=5}]
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=0.1, xmin=15, xmax=50,
xtick={15,20,...,50},
ytick={0,0.01,...,0.1},
grid={major},clip=false,grid style={dashed},
title={},
legend style={at={(1.2 ,1)},anchor=north},
font=\footnotesize,
scaled y ticks=false,
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
]

% 25
\addplot[color=green, mark=*, samples=10] [error bars/.cd,y dir=both, y explicit] coordinates {
(15, 0.0032)
(20, 0.0039) 
(25, 0.0052) 
(30, 0.007)
(35, 0.009)
(40, 0.0095) 
(45, 0.01)
(50, 0.012)
};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[]{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot that did work in this figure but did not in another one. I can not see why as they look similar. Can you copy and past the other one for me and check why the solution is not working. I will add the code to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @AliAlzahrani You should better ask a new question why the code in the other figure doesn't work